# Prevent to show state change of the Facebook login button

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-3.14.x

I am using the Facebook login button for authentication and followed pretty much the [Facebook Login for Android](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/v2.0) tutorial.

In the `onSessionStateChange` method I make a Graph API call to retrieve the User ID:

```
Request request = Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
        // ...
    }
 });

request.executeAsync();
```

In the meantime, I don't wish the Facebook Login Button does not change from *Log in with Facebook* to *Log Out*. Any idea how to achieve this in an easy way? I reckon it might be even possible in the layout XML file, but I have not found an appropriate attribute.